# Botan SSL/TLS example or starting point

Tags: c++, ssl, botan

I am experimenting with the Botan library to establish a SSL/TLS connection with a private certificate. Unfortunately I cannot found any actual sample code using the new TLS::Client class. The documentation is barely some more text to the doxygen doc. Is there any project out there using Botan where I can see, how a connection can established? I am agnostic to which compiler or OS is used as my project has to be platform independent anyway.

Comment: Hey @Martin, did you find anything?

Comment: @PeeS unfortunatly no.

Comment: this is so bad. OpenSSL is a disaster i was hoping Botan will be an 'easy' thing to keep going - another useless lib with no examples.

Comment: I know this thread is old. I just found [this](https://archive.is/mstSu#selection-192.5-192.6) old piece of code. It is now a bit outdated but gives an idea.

Answer (score 2):

The best open source examples for using the api at this point are probably the uses by the `botan` command line tool in `src/cmd/tls_client.cpp`, and also `src/cmd/tls_proxy.cpp` which is server side but additionally demonstrates how to tie into asio.